# QuickAppend existing zip files to a zip file - in PHP

Tags: php, zip

I was wondering if there is a similar method in PHP to combine multiple zip files into one new zip-file without recompressing the contents - like this zip file library:

http://www.example-code.com/vb/zip_appendFilesToExistingZip.asp

Reason I ask is because of this article on fast file zipping for Amazon S3:

http://www.w2lessons.com/2012/01/fast-zipping-in-amazon-s3.html

See why:

> Upon inspecting the Chilkat API, I noticed the existence of a
>   QuickAppend method which serves to append one zip to another. I began
>   wondering how the compression time would be affected if we pre-zipped
>   each file in S3, in its destination directory structure, and then
>   simply appended them all together to form the final zip. To my dismay,
>   the difference in compression time was astonishing. Small zip files in
>   the 100kb-300kb range saw a 2x-3x speed improvement, while those
>   larger than 10mb saw a 10x – 15x improvement. For example, a 14mb zip
>   with 25 files varying in size from 100kb to 8mb took a mere 120ms to
>   compress into the final zip, while building the zip from scratch took
>   over 1.5 seconds.

Anybody know a similar technique in PHP?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I didn't look to deep into the Chillkat extensions, they seem to have a PHP extension as well. See: http://www.example-code.com/phpExt/zip_appendFilesToExistingZip.asp

However, my question now would be - **is there an open-source PHP library** that does the same thing?