# How to concatenate zip files in PHP

Tags: php, zip

I've built a zip file using ZipArchive that contains a directory structure like this:

```
analysis_name /
    attachment_file_1.pdf
    attachment_file_2.jpg
    attachment_file_3.jpg
    attachment_file_4.jpg
    attachment_file_5.xlsx
```

That's all fine, and I can have the user download it without any worries. The requirement is that they need to be able to fit multiple analyses into a zip file so that we have something like this:

```
analysis_name_1 /
    attachment_file_1_1.pdf
    attachment_file_1_2.jpg
    ...
analysis_name_2 /
    attachment_file_2_1.pdf
    attachment_file_2_2.jpg
    ...
analysis_name_n /
    attachment_file_3_1.pdf
    attachment_file_3_2.jpg
    ...
```

The problem I'm facing is that these combined zip files can't exceed 16 MB because they have to be uploaded into a different site. So let's say that I have 20 analyses, ranging in size from 500 K to 6 MB. If I was using gzip, I'm pretty sure I could make the individual analysis gzips, greedily concatenate them until the next file would exceed the 16 MB, and then start a new file.

Is it possible to do this with zip files? I'm not keen on converting gzips to zips because the resulting file may turn out to be larger than the 16 MB.

I noticed [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22996654/quickappend-existing-zip-files-to-a-zip-file-in-php), and like that writer, I'm looking for an open source solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I ended up doing goes along these lines:

1. Make a zip file for each analysis, putting it in /tmp and ensuring that the name is unique.
2. Put these temporary zip files and their sizes into a list, sorting by size, largest first.
3. Create a "real" zip file, and iterate through the list of temporary files.
4. If the size of the "real" zip file plus the size of the current temporary zip file is less than the limit, add the files that went into the temp zip file into the real zip file. If the files can be added, remove the temporary zip file from the list and the /tmp directory.
5. If a "real" zip file is full and we still have temporary zips, create a new "real" file and go back to step 4.

So that gives a list of zip files that are guaranteed to be less than the limit, and should be the fewest in number.

There are a couple of caveats:

1. If you have a single analysis that zips up and is above the limit, you'll have to handle it yourself. This algorithm won't do it.
2. The limit I use internally is 1 MB smaller than the actual limit because I'm not sure about whether the size of zipped(m) + zipped(n) is guaranteed to be bigger than zipped(m + n).

While you could implement this in PHP, I ended up writing it in Python because it had to be done in a background process due to responsiveness, and because of the requirement that the user be able to download the resulting zip files more than once if necessary. Somewhat arbitrarily, I've chosen to do all background processing in Python.

Comment: Thanks for that, Ignacio ... however, what I was really looking for was something that would do it nicely with zip files, where I wouldn't have to zip them twice. I could do it with gzip files, but couldn't find anything to work with zip files. Failed. So I just did the double zipping thing.

Comment: If you "store" (0% compression) the files then you can just calculate the fixed overhead for the zip file and knapsack away.